# removing specific style from wp_head

Tags: php, wordpress

im not a wp developer , im trying to help a frient who has a wp website
here is the problem

in the template `wp_head()` functions adds bunch of styles and scripts like

i want to remove some of them in some pages lets say this one

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='yasrcss-css'  href='https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/css/yasr.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

so i searched around and based on what have been suggested on other questions i added this lines to function.php (inside theme folder)

```
add_action('init','_remove_style');

function _remove_style(){

    wp_dequeue_style('yasrcss-css');
    wp_dequeue_style('yasr.css');
}
```

it didnt work  , also i added this fo function.php

```
wp_deregister_style('yasrcss-css');
```

this one didnt work eather

am i missing something , is there anything else i should do ?

btw i tried this code

```
printf( 
    '<pre>%s</pre>', 
    var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered, TRUE )
);
```

as suggested here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213862/remove-specific-css-and-js-from-the-head

i didnt that particle css in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP `init` hook is not for loading/unloading assets. You can try and use [`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) instead:

```
// Replace

add_action('init', '_remove_style');

// With

add_action('wp_loaded', '_remove_style');
```